# Premiere Pro system compatibility report unsupported video drivers

Tags: video, premiere, software, hardware

Just had to wipe my windows installation as it got beyond repair.  Working on a Lenovo P50, 32GB memory, Core i7 HD, Intel HD Graphics 530, Nvidia Quadro M1000M.  I've got a clean install of windows, I've installed the latest version (grudgingly) of Premiere Pro.  Open it for the first time, I get a window I haven't seen before:

[image]

(FYI, at first, this showed both my video drivers as unsupported.  The other is a Nvidia Quadro M1000M)

That's weird, I think.  I click on `Fix...`

- Fix for the Intel Graphics driver takes me to: https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/drivers-video-win-intel.html
- Fix for the Nvidia driver takes me to: https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/drivers-video-win-nvidia.html

Wasn't keen on messing with the Nvidia GPU, so I thought I'd give the Intel a go first.  Downloaded the file but when I try to install I get:

[image]

So then I did `Win` + `X` and click on Device Manager.  When I update the drivers for either Nvidia or Intel, using the search online option, I get told that I've got the latest drivers.

Ok, let's have a look at Nvidia I think - go to the website, stick in the right version, download and clean install the latest drivers, and boom, the problem goes away for Premiere Pro and everything seems to be functioning normally.  (Hence the first screenshot not showing a problem with Nvidia any more)

Well, the Intel error in Premiere doesn't bother me if Premiere will work with the Nvidia driver.  So I either want to fix it or make it go away.

I downloaded the Intel tool which detects your hardware and recommends the right drivers.  This says:

[image]

So then I found this link online: https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects/faq-what-is-system-compatibility-report-in-after-effects-and-premiere-pro/td-p/11200108?page=1 where an answer led me to look at this link: https://www.howtogeek.com/343287/how-to-fix-the-driver-being-installed-is-not-validated-for-this-computer-on-intel-computers

BUT there's a caveat which applies to my laptop:
[image]

I ran the Lenovo system update tool, hoping for an Intel driver update from the manufacturer, but I have all the latest packages for my system.

So what should I do?  My understanding is that if I force the update to Intel's latest driver, this could cause compatibility issues where it integrates with the Nvidia driver, and possibly Lenovo's other drivers.  On the other hand, I use Premiere Pro a lot, and I don't want to live with error popups and notifications whenever I use it.  If the error isn't going to bother me I'd be happy just to hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where possible, it seems best to disable the Intel integrated graphics if you have dual graphics.  Install the latest graphics from Nvidia for the Nvidia graphics card, and Premiere Pro should be good.

If you have discrete graphics you might not be able to disable the integrated graphics.  However this also means it doesn't matter if you update the discrete GPU.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to open a new project on premiere, go to "edit", preferences, general and uncheck "show system compatibility issues at startup".
This will make that thing desappear, but it won't fix any issue.
Anyway, i hope it helps.
Bye!
Bizzarra